# How to cross compile system tap scripts for user space application

Tags: linux, debugging, system, systemtap

The challenge that I faced was on identifying the process name / library name within the script.During the cross compilation the process name and library name are being referred with real path of process/library in the host (which I understood after peeked the generated .ko).

Since the real path of host and target are different, the cross compiled instrumentation is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See also the stap `--sysroot=/PATH` and `--sysenv=VAR=VALUE` options.

Comment: Thanks fche that shall work. But unfortunately I am hitting this bug - https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17231

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to fix; interested in giving it a try?  We can help.